# Global Variable not Retaining Content

Tags: ios, swift

I have a global variable in my class called contacts initialized as - var contacts: [Name]

towards the top of my class. I am wondering why the array is not retaining the populated values. Where the array gets reset is in the comments in the code below.

```
func extractFromPhone()->[Name]{

  swiftAddressBook?.requestAccessWithCompletion({ (success, error) -> Void in
        if success {
            if let people : [SwiftAddressBookPerson]? = swiftAddressBook?.allPeople {
                for person in people! {

                    // Get Names
                    var name: Name = Name();
                    {
                        name.nickName = nickname;
                    }
                    if let fn = person.firstName
                    {
                        name.firstName = fn;
                    }
                    if let mn = person.middleName
                    {
                        name.middleName = mn;
                    }
                    if let ln = person.lastName
                    {
                        name.lastName = ln;
                    }


                     contacts.append(name);
                }
            }
        }
        else {
        }
// contacts array properly filled here
    })

// contacts array becomes empty here
}
```

Comment: you can't have a global variable in a class, also don't make global variables. It is almost impossible to have a question about swift, obj-c, xcode and ios

Comment: Can you include more code from the class?  Specifically, what the class definition is and where the global variable is defined.

Comment: Your code is in a closure/block. Therefore, it's being run asynchronously, and will most likely complete after your code hits the end of function. That's what is causing you to not see the populated array. If you've noticed, a breakpoint within your closure will be hit after your breakpoint at the end of your function. You should do some reading on closures if you aren't familiar with them. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html